# How to make interface between fragment and RecyclerView Adapter for the purpose to get onActivityResult() from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragment is containing `RecyclerView` in which data is populating through `Adapter` which is:

```
MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{
    ...
}
```

The `imageButton` is in `ViewHolder` which will make the intent to choose image from the gallery which work fine but the problem is `onActivityResult()` is not working in adapter. Please tell me the way to get the `onActivityResult()` form `Fragment` so that I can get the `uri` of chosen image to make further process on it.

Comment: If i were in your shoes, i will just make the adapter a inner-class inside the fragment class.

Comment: oh mannnn you sloved it. Few words but very life saving words. how can I vote for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try defining an interface that can be used to communicate with the fragment or you could define a public method that you call when you receive a call to onActivityResult() in your activity like this:

In your activity implement onActivityResult() and pass the result to your fragment:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    YourFragment mFragment;
    //rest of code

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        mFragment.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    //rest of code
}
```

In your fragment define a public method to pass the result received from your activity:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{

    public void handleActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //handle result
    }
}
```

Again, you could also do this with an interface if you like.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The problem is solved by shifting the separate adapter class to inner class in fragment. so by this way headache of getting `onResultActivity()` gone.